# How can I use sass maps with SASS syntax (not SCSS)?

Tags: sass, preprocessor, scss-lint

When I am trying to use this code

```
$column-width: (
    first: 210px
    second: 200px
    third: 100px
    )

@each $column, $width in $column-width
    .col-#{$column}
        width: $width
```

I have got an error

```
Message:
    _sass\grid.sass
Error: unclosed parenthesis
        on line 1 of _sass/grid.sass
>> $column-width: ( {
   ---------------^
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Sass mappings and indented syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23808514/sass-mappings-and-indented-syntax)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SASS doesn't support multiline syntax for maps.

The solution at present moment

```
$column-width: (first: 210px, second: 200px, third: 100px)
```